# Calling an web service from java program

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to call an web service by sending an xml file as input and i should be receiving an xml as a reply but whenever i send the xml i get proxy authentication error so i thought i was sending the wrong xml but the same xml works fine when i use SOAP UI so i guess there is some problem with my code.

Here is the code below

URL url = null;

```
   String strUrl="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\" xmlns:soap=\"SoapAuthenticator\" xmlns:ship=\"http://ws.consignorsupport.no/ShipAdvisor\"><soapenv:Header> <soap:ServiceAuthenticationHeader><soap:Username>TDC43671</soap:Username> <soap:Password>hTiNMft/KaMfDDD</soap:Password><soap:IsEncrypted>false</soap:IsEncrypted></soap:ServiceAuthenticationHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ship:SearchForDropPoints><ship:productConceptID>92</ship:productConceptID><ship:installationID>00000000018</ship:installationID><ship:country>DK</ship:country><ship:address></ship:address><ship:postCode>6000</ship:postCode><ship:city></ship:city><ship:limit>5</ship:limit></ship:SearchForDropPoints></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

String ss="http://www.consignorsupport.no/ShipAdvisor/Main.asmx";

url = new URL(ss);

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);
 conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml, application/xml");
  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.connect();

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

   wr.write(strUrl);
   wr.flush();
   wr.close();


   int iHttpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
  String  strErrorMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

  System.out.println("Getting Response status");
  System.out.println(iHttpResponseCode);

  System.out.println(strErrorMessage);
```

Can anybode help me as to where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a proxyauthentication error, chances are that that really is the issue. Maybe soap ui is set up with the correct proxy info? Or gets it from the system settings? Your java code won't automatically pick up on these settings. Check if you have a system proxy configured, or one in soapUI.